# 400 Error while trying to POST to JIRA issue

Tags: python, json, api, jira

I am trying to set the 'transition' property in a JIRA issue from whatever it is, to completed(which according to the doc is 10000). According to the documentation, this error is 'If there is no transition specified.'

Also I have used ?expand=transitions.fields to verify that 10000 is for complete.

using these docs 
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-doTransition
https://jira.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/resource/api-2-issue-issueidorkey-transitions/POST

Here is my request

```
url = 'http://MYURL/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-ID/transitions'
payload1 = open('data3.json', 'r').read()
payload = json.loads(payload1)
textFile = requests.post(url, auth=('username', 'password'), json=payload)
```

The contents on my data3.json file are

```
{
"transition": 10000
}
```

edit: I also changed my JSON to this and I get a 500 error

```
{
"transition": {
    "id": "10000"
   }
}
```

The error I get

```
{"errorMessages":["Can not instantiate value of type [simple type,classcom.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.TransitionBean] from JSON integral number;no single-int-arg constructor/factory method (through reference chain:com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean[\"transition\"])"]}400
```

I'm pretty confident that my issue is in my json file since I have used GET in the code above this snippit multiple times, but I could be wrong.

Possible cause - https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-32132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue I was having was a process flow one. I cannot jump right from my issue being opened, to 'completed'. However, I can go from the issue being created to 'Done'.

```
{
"transition": {
    "name": "Done",
    "id": "151"
    }
}
```

As this does what I need, I will use it. If I find how to make  ticket complete I will post back.

Also, I think the fact we customize our JIRA lead to my getting 'Completed' as a valid transition even though it wasn't.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you're right that the JSON is wrong, it's not even a valid json since the value is not a number, string, object, or array. The doc says:

> The fields that can be set on transtion, in either the fields
>   parameter or the update parameter can be determined using the
>   /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
>   resource.

So you need to do a get request on `/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions?expand=transitions.fields` to get the list of possible values and then set that in the json

```
{
 "transition": {
     "id" : "an_id_from_response"
 }
}
```

Comment: I looked and I found "name":"Completed","id":"10000" (also did you refresh this page 9 minutes ago? The value was not 10000. I accidentally had it set to a wrong paste.

Comment: Also my json looks fine on JSON Lint

Comment: Ok, before it was wrong.  Well does your json look anything like the example request that they provide in the first link?  No.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I updated right when I saw I had put it in wrong. It does look like the request. I don't need all of that information. All that is optional according to JIRA. I am only supposed to need the transition id.

Comment: Can you post the response from a GET request on `/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions`?